# How to make an advanced plot with this structure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a specific plot to visualize my data. It consists of an ID and 4 values, the first is a value that should be shifted on the x-axis depending on the value, the second and third are the beginning and end of an interval and the fourth is just a value that is part of the data point and should be at the end aligned with the others. I made a picture in paint to show what I'm trying to acomplish:

[image]

Here is the corresponding data:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
v1 <- c(3,4,3,6,5,1)
v2 <- c(5,6,6,9,8,4)
v3 <- c(10,12,12,15,12,13)
v4 <- c(1,2,1,1,4,3)
df <- data.frame(id,v1,v2,v3,v4)

  id v1 v2 v3 v4
1  1  3  5 10  1
2  2  4  6 12  2
3  3  3  6 12  1
4  4  6  9 15  1
5  5  5  8 12  4
6  6  1  4 13  3
```

I'm familair with ggplot2, the intervals look like confidence intervals so maybe I can do something with that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a combination of `geom_point`, `geom_segment` and `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=id,y=v1), size=4, color="red") +
  geom_segment(aes(x=id, xend=id, y=v2, yend=v3), size=2) +
  geom_text(aes(x=id, y=16, label=v4)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=id) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:

[image]

Another option is using `geom_errorbar` instead of `geom_segment`:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=id,y=v1), size=4, color="red") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=id, ymin=v2, ymax=v3), size=2, width=0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(x=id, y=16, label=v4)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=id) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

this results in:

[image]